# why is it that I log in at feb 8 but I can't log out at feb 9. It always show "cannot time out. No time in"

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an employee log in system for both dayshift and night shift. dayshift log ins 100% working but at night they log in at feb 8 11pm and the can't log out at feb 9. Here is my code

```
if($status == 'out'){
    $sql = "SELECT *, attendance.id AS uid FROM attendance LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=attendance.employee_id WHERE attendance.employee_id = '$id' AND date = '$date_now' ";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows < 1){
        $output['error'] = true;
        $output['message'] = 'Cannot Timeout. No time in.';
    }
    else{
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        if($row['time_out'] != '00:00:00'){
            $output['error'] = false;
            $output['message'] = 'Time out: '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];

        }
        else{
            
            $sql = "UPDATE attendance SET time_out = NOW() WHERE id = '".$row['uid']."'";
```

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems confused; you are comparing time_out to 00:00:00, but setting it to NOW(); is it a time or a datetime?  If it is a time, you don't want to use the value 00:00:00 to mean not clocked out, or you won't be able to have people actually clock out right at midnight.  It would be better to use time_out of NULL to mean not clocked out.

In any case, if there are overnight shifts, you need to look for attendance records for the previous day too.  I would suggest looking for shifts with a date of either yesterday or today, but preferring ones with time_out not set.

```
SELECT *, attendance.id AS uid
FROM attendance
LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=attendance.employee_id
WHERE attendance.employee_id = ? AND date IN (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY, DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY time_out IS NOT NULL, date DESC, time_out DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why would you want the attendance fir non-existing employees?

Comment: for my company because our timesheet is in excel and biometrics they can log in at the excel even if they haven't at the office yet

Comment: "nothing happen" isn't helpful.  Please show some sample data where you expect to get a row and you aren't getting one and the exact query you are trying

Comment: Why `DATE(NOW())` instead of `CURDATE()`?

Comment: @Dharman just because it's easier to change if what they really want is the date in timezone X.  if you like curdate, use it.

Answer (score -1):

In your SQL query you have a condition as `AND date = '$date_now' "`.

Try viewing you value on `$date_now` and check manually on your database table if there exists the same value on `date` column.

Your date now value should exist on the database to return the query results.